# Google Play Report error regarding JQMath file in android

Tags: android, android-security, jqmath

ERROR REPORT ON GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE

> Your app contains one or more libraries with known security issues.
> Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
>
> JavaScript jquery 1.4.3 SNYK-npm:jquery:20110606,
> SNYK-npm:jquery:20150627, SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006
> assets/jquery-1.4.3.min.js, assets/jquery-1.4.3.js

I only download the jqmath module to help formulate my math functions in the android mobile application, Please what can I do?

Comment: The jquery version you listed is **very old**. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases

Comment: Even [jqMath's](https://github.com/luxp/jqmath/blob/master/package.json#L7) dependencies say around 3.2.1

Comment: Please check this once
https://www.privacy-wise.com/mitigating-cve-2019-11358-in-old-versions-of-jquery/